# jQuery timed repeating Slideshow

Tags: jquery, timer, slideshow

The code below swaps the first pic to the second pic correctly but doesnt continue to 3 and 4 and start over.

```
= function () {

    var $active = $('#challengeTwoImageJq .carouselImagejQueryActive');
    var $next = ($('#challengeTwoImageJq .carouselImagejQueryActive').next().length > 0) ? $('#challengeTwoImageJq .carouselImagejQueryActive').next() : $('#challengeTwoImageJq img:first');
    timer = setInterval(function () {

        $active.removeClass('carouselImagejQueryActive');
        $next.fadeIn().addClass('carouselImagejQueryActive');

    }, 3000);


    timer = setInterval('challengeTwoJquery()', 3000);

}
```

HTML

```
<div id='challengeTwoImageJq' class='sectionChallengeCarouselImage'>
    <img id='imgq1' imgn='1' class='carouselImage carouselImagejQueryActive' src='img/image1.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgq2' imgn='2' class='carouselImage' src='img/image2.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgq3' imgn='3' class='carouselImage' src='img/image3.jpg'/>
    <img id='imgq4' imgn='4' class='carouselImage' src='img/image4.jpg'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Just looking at the code with no markup, I suspect duplicate Id's here.

Comment: As far as I can tell the function runs once and then stops. How do I get it to loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want them to display/cycle you could do:

```
function runem() {
    var allofEm = $('#challengeTwoImageJq img');
    var $active = allofEm.eq(0);
    $active.show();
    var $next = $active.next();
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $next.fadeIn();
        $active.hide();
        $active = $next;
        $next = (allofEm.last().index() == allofEm.index($active)) ?
            $next = allofEm.eq(0):$active.next();

    }, 3000);
}
runem();
```

You might be able to simplify it some though. And you don't need the function unless you really want it.

EDIT: just to be clear, I assume this CSS at the start:

```
#challengeTwoImageJq img {display:none;}
```

see it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8Mp7T/

Comment: I tested that just to see and it didnt work for me. But I would prefer to stick to what I had originally just figure out why it isnt looping. Thanks

Comment: @CUDA - what you originally had does not work.  This is because it unsets the class and never resets either of the $active or $next variables to new values - which my code does.  IF you need the class added/removed, you can do that at the point where the $active and $next are set in my code...

Comment: I got it working! I realized what I did wrong. Thanks Mark. You got me looking in the right direction